# executeUpdate in grails

Tags: grails, hql

I´m looking to do this with executeUpdate, the thing is concat a string value with executeUpdate in GRAILS

```
def transactions = Transaction.findAll()

for (tr in transactions) {
   tr.comment = tr.comment + " new words...."
   tr.save()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried but something like this

```
Transaction.executeUpdate("update Transaction t set t.comment=t.comment + :newComment", [newComment: 'new words...'])
```

OR

```
Transaction.executeUpdate("update Transaction t set t.comment=concat(t.comment, :newComment), [newComment: 'new words...'])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   def transactions = Transaction.all  //you can use  findAll() also
    for (Transaction tr : transactions) {
       tr.comment = tr.comment + " new words...."
       tr.save(flush:true)
    }
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: Sure It works Rahul, but the idea is not iterate in records and do it in one query,

Comment: @israel-laguna  i think you required to write native query